# Как применить стиль к соседнему элементу?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Хочу сделать чтобы при активации radio input происходило изменение фона у div расположенного внутри тега label.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#content-id1 {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

#content-id1>label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#content-id1>label>input {}

#content-id1>label>div {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#content-id1>label>input:checked div {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-id1">
  <h3>Один или два?</h3>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><div></div>1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><div></div>2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо использовать `+` - который выбирает первого правого соседа: `div` на том же уровне вложенности, который идёт сразу после `input`

то есть `#content-id1>label>input:checked + div`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#content-id1 {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

#content-id1>label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#content-id1>label>input {}

#content-id1>label>div {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#content-id1>label>input:checked + div {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-id1">
  <h3>Один или два?</h3>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><div></div>1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><div></div>2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ)

Comment: @123213asdasdas, а если нужен элемент, который находится на одном уровне, но не рядом, то используйте `~`

Comment: @Yuri так выбираются элемент**ы**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, всё равно вопрос - дубликат :)

Comment: @123213asdasdas пока не закрыли как дубль - жми галочку :D